# Can I make a lambda argument required?

Tags: typescript

I would like to pass a lambda into a function, but require a lambda with a single argument.  TypeScript throws an error, as desired, if I pass two parameters into the lambda, but does not complain if I omit any parameters from the lambda.  How can I get TypeScript to require a single parameter lambda to be passed?

```
function foo(fn: (x) => any) { }

foo(() => "bla");     // Bad, but no error
foo((x) => "bla");    // Good, no error
foo((x, y) => "bla"); // Bad, with error
```

Comment: `() => "bla"` is assignable to `(x) => any`. Practically, even if the limitation existed it still could not enforce a function to use that argument for antyhing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually the intended behavior, for better or worse. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

Unfortunately there is no way I know of to get the behavior that you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, semantically, `x => "bla"` and `() => "bla"` are completely identical. They both completely ignore the first parameter (and all the rest, as well)

By asking for an `(x) => any` lambda, you're basically saying, "I want something that I can call with one parameter", `() => "bla"` fits the bill, `(x, y) => "bla"` does not.